# Consecutively copy two lines and skip the third using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

With fairly simply `awk`:

```
awk '(NR%3)' awk.write
```

for this file:

```
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
but not 1
THIS is not
butbutbut ffff
second line
```

I have output as:

```
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
but not 1
THIS is not
second line
```

But the last line is not wanted since it doesn't qualify the definition of consecutive.

How can I the get the first two of every three consecutive lines?

Comment: How about when the third is absent? Example in `seq 8 | awk ...`, should `7` and `8` printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable to track if the previous line is present or not:

```
$ awk '
  FNR % 3 == 1 {f = $0; next}  # The first line keep in f, skip to next line
  FNR % 3 && f {print f;print} # Previous line present, print it and current line
' <file
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
but not 1
THIS is not
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -ne 'N;/\n/p;N;d' <file
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't get how the last line is eliminated from printing what I see that the `f` contains first line of two consecutive lines and `next` just moves to next line which be empty so condition is false.Please explain

Comment: This approach just delay the print of the first line, it's only printed if and only if there is a second. If there is no second line, then nothing is print.